# How to add a custom header to doorkeper token response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

The project that I'm working on requires me to add custom headers based on generated response body to all responses generated by my app. This works fine with after_action in my application controller, but I also need to add the custom header to the token responses generated with Doorkeeper. I setting base_controller to ApplicationController in doorkeeper configuration, but this did not cause my after_actions to be called. Are there some possible workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it takes one to define a custom Doorkeeper::TokensController class and add an filter to it.

app/controllers/access_tokens_controller.rb:

```
class AccessTokensController < Doorkeeper::TokensController
  include AbstractController::Callbacks
  after_action :add_signature_to_response, only: [:create]

  def add_signature_to_response
    application = strategy.client.application
    # ...
    # response_based_on_application = ...
    # ... 
    response.headers['custom-header'] = response_based_on_application
  end
end
```

Next one needs to register that controller in doorkeeper configuration in config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb

```
# ...
use_doorkeeper scope: 'oauth2' do
  # ...
  controllers tokens: 'access_tokens'
  # ...
end
# ...
```